# Auto-run a command on saving in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin, sublimelinter

Is it possible to run `eslint` automatically when I save either a `.js` or `.jsx` file in Sublime Text?

I'm using the [ESLint sublime package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ESLint) right now but I have to manually run it each time using `Cmd + Option + e`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this can be done with a simple event driven plugin like the one I've written below.

The plugin has been tested but not with the `eslint` command since I did not want to install that package. Clearly any command could be run instead of `eslint` in the plugin's `run_command("eslint")` line. If the desired command takes args then they can be specified like this: `run_command("command", {"arg_1": val, "arg_2": val})`.

The `on_post_save_async(self, view)` method (in my plugin below) will be called after the `view`, i.e. the active buffer, has been saved - note that this includes auto-saves. `on_post_save_async()` runs in a separate thread and does not block the application. You could alter the plugin to use a similar method depending of whether you want `eslint` called before or after the file save has taken place and whether the method should block the application or be run in its own non-blocking thread. These are the 4 alternatives:

- `on_pre_save(self, view)`: Called just before a view is saved. It blocks the application until the method returns.
- `on_pre_save_async(self, view)`: Called just before a view is saved. Runs in a separate thread, and does not block the application.
- `on_post_save(self, view)`: Called after a view has been saved. It blocks the application until the method returns.
- `on_post_save_async(self, view)`: Called after a view has been saved. Runs in a separate thread, and does not block the application. [*Currently used in the plugin below.*]
- The Sublime Text `EventListener` documentation [is located here](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.EventListener) - there are on load methods too.

Save the plugin below somewhere in in your Sublime Text packages hierarchy with a `.py` extension. e.g. `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/AutoRunESLintOnSave.py` and it should work straight away.

```py
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class AutoRunESLintOnSave(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    """ A class to listen for events triggered by ST. """

    def on_post_save_async(self, view):
        """
        This is called after a view has been saved. It runs in a separate thread
        and does not block the application.
        """

        file_path = view.file_name()
        if not file_path:
            return
        NOT_FOUND = -1
        pos_dot = file_path.rfind(".")
        if pos_dot == NOT_FOUND:
            return
        file_extension = file_path[pos_dot:]
        if file_extension.lower() in [".js", ".jsx"]:
            view.window().run_command("eslint")

            # Slight variations are needed for an ApplicationCommand,
            # a WindowCommand, or a TextCommand.
            #
            # view.run_command("text_command")
            # view.window().run_command("window_command")
            # sublime.run_command("application_command")
            #
            # Need args? Use this:
            #
            # view.run_command("command", {"arg_1": val, "arg_2": val})
```

Instead of using file extensions to trigger running the `eslint` command you could use the buffer's syntax, the code is even more concise.

```py
    def on_post_save_async(self, view):
        """ Syntax version. """

        current_syntax = view.settings().get("syntax")
        if ("JavaScript.sublime-syntax" in current_syntax
                or "JSX.sublime-syntax" in current_syntax):
            view.window().run_command("eslint")

        # You could, of course, use an exact match:
        #
        # current_syntax = view.settings().get("syntax")
        # if current_syntax == "Packages/JavaScript/JavaScript.sublime-syntax":
        #     view.window().run_command("eslint")
        #
        # Run `view.settings().get("syntax")` in the console for the active syntax path.
```

Comment: Thanks, got it to work after adding `.window()` after `view`.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show the variations in the way `run_command("command")` is called depeding on whether `command` is an `ApplicationCommand`, a `WindowCommand`, or a `TextCommand`.