# Sublime plugin for executing a command

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I been writing markdown files lately, and have been using the awesome **table of content generator** ([github-markdown-toc](https://github.com/ekalinin/github-markdown-toc)) tool/script on a daily basis, but I'd like it to be regenerated automatically each time I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>, right before saving the md file in my sublime3 environment.

What I have done till now was to generate it from the shell manually, using:

```
gh-md-toc --insert my_file.md
```

So I wrote a simple plugin, but for some reason I can't see the result I wanted.
I see my print but the toc is not generated.
Does anybody has any suggestions? what's wrong?

```py
import sublime, sublime_plugin
import subprocess

class AutoRunTOCOnSave(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    """ A class to listen for events triggered by ST. """

    def on_post_save_async(self, view):
        """
        This is called after a view has been saved. It runs in a separate thread
        and does not block the application.
        """

        file_path = view.file_name()

        if not file_path:
            return
        NOT_FOUND = -1
        pos_dot = file_path.rfind(".")
        if pos_dot == NOT_FOUND:
            return
        file_extension = file_path[pos_dot:]
        if file_extension.lower() == ".md": #
            print("Markdown TOC was invoked: handling with *.md file")
            subprocess.Popen(["gh-md-toc", "--insert ",  file_path])
```

Comment: The plugin you wrote?! That's the plugin I wrote and posted in response to the StackOverflow [Auto-run a command on saving in Sublime Text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60249097/2102457) question. At best that's very bad netiquette JammingThebBits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, since **gh-md-toc** is a bash script, I replaced the following line:

```
subprocess.Popen(["gh-md-toc", "--insert ",  file_path])
```

with:

```
subprocess.check_call("gh-md-toc --insert %s" % file_path, shell=True)
```

So now it works well, on each save.

Comment: This was going to be my next suggestion. Glad you got it to work!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly modified version of your plugin:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

import subprocess


class AutoRunTOCOnSaveListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    """ A class to listen for events triggered by ST. """

    def on_post_save_async(self, view):
        """
        This is called after a view has been saved. It runs in a separate thread
        and does not block the application.
        """

        file_path = view.file_name()
        if not file_path:
            return
        
        if file_path.split(".")[-1].lower() == "md":
            print("Markdown TOC was invoked: handling with *.md file")
            subprocess.Popen(["/full/path/to/gh-md-toc", "--insert ",  file_path])
```

I changed a couple things, along with the name of the class. First, I simplified your test for determining if the current file is a Markdown document (fewer operations means less room for error). Second, you should include the full path to the `gh-md-toc` command, as it's possible `subprocess.Popen` can't find it on the default path.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the code cleanup (I appreciate it),
but with the full path I still got nothing.

Comment: You can simplify the detect even further with `if not self.view.match_selector(0, 'text.html.markdown'): return` to detect when the file is markdown, regardless of the extension it has (if you use an alternate syntax you may need to swap the `scope` used though).

Comment: @OdatNurd that's why I didn't go for detecting scope. I suppose you could argue that Markdown files can have other extensions, but I decided to stay with what the OP had, just clean it up a bit.

Comment: As mentioned in a comment (above) in response to the OP, the plugin was actually mine from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60249097/2102457). In that answer I offered code to check the syntax as a more concise alternative to the filename check originally requested.